# Why am I getting a TypeError not a function. Calling forEach on an array object

Tags: javascript

For a bit of background information: this app is supposed to load a map api and create a workout form linked to a location selected on the map by clicking. Once the map is clicked, a form is loaded to fill out info about that workout and then it's saved to the #workout variable.

Problem: I'm trying to save the #workout variable to local storage to then load all the workouts from storage whenever the page is reloaded.

I'm trying to run the _getLocalStorage() function in the constructor to load items from the local storage when the page loads, but I keep getting this TypeError code:

```
script.js:239 Uncaught TypeError: this[#workout].forEach is not a function
    at App._getLocalStorage (script.js:239)
    at new App (script.js:21)
```

Code:

```
class App {
    #map;
    #mapEvent;
    #workout = [];
    constructor() {
        this._getPosition();
        
        this._getLocalStorage();
        
        form.addEventListener('submit', this._newWorkout.bind(this));
        
        inputType.addEventListener('change', this._toggleElevationField);
        containerWorkouts.addEventListener('click', this._panToWorkout.bind(this));
    }
    
    _panToWorkout(e) {
        // find the workout
        
        const workoutEl = e.target.closest('.workout');
        
        if (!workoutEl) return;
        
        const workout = this.#workout.find(
            work => work.id === workoutEl.dataset.id
        );
        
        // pan to workout object with that id number
        this.#map.setView(workout.coords, 13, {
            animate: true,
            pan: {
                duration: 1,
                easeLinearity: 0.8,
            },
        });
    }
    
    _getPosition() {
        // -> check if this nagivator.geolocation object exits, then loads the map.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                this._loadMap.bind(this),
                function () {
                    alert("Can't get your position");
                }
            );
        }
    }
    
    _loadMap(position) {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        
        // -> creating a coordinate variable because the below L.map().setView function expects an array for the coordinates.
        
        // -> adding the map loading script from the imported library after getting coordinates
        this.#map = L.map('map').setView([latitude, longitude], 13);
        
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(
            this.#map
        );
        
        // -> SETUP MAP CLICK LISTENER && OPEN FORM
        this.#map.on('click', this._showForm.bind(this));
    }
    
    _showForm(event) {
        this.#mapEvent = event;
        form.classList.remove('hidden');
        inputDistance.focus();
    }
    _hideForm() {
        // -> Clear form values when submit
        inputDistance.value =
            inputCadence.value =
            inputDuration.value =
            inputElevation.value =
            '';
        // -> removes the form from view to disable the slide transition while it's being removed.
        form.style.display = 'none';
        
        form.classList.add('hidden');
        
        setTimeout(() => (form.style.display = 'grid'), 1000);
    }
    _toggleElevationField() {
        inputElevation.closest('.form__row').classList.toggle('form__row--hidden');
        inputCadence.closest('.form__row').classList.toggle('form__row--hidden');
    }
    _newWorkout(e) {
        // -> prevent default submit function which is to refresh the page
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const validInput = (...inputs) =>
            inputs.every(entry => Number.isFinite(entry));
        
        const allPositive = (...inputs) => inputs.every(inp => inp > 0);
        
        // -> Get data from form
        const type = inputType.value;
        const distance = +inputDistance.value;
        const duration = +inputDuration.value;
        const { lat, lng } = this.#mapEvent.latlng;
        let workout;
        
        // -> if running, create running object
        if (type === 'running') {
            // -> check if data is valid
            const cadence = +inputCadence.value;
            if (
                !validInput(distance, duration, cadence) ||
                    !allPositive(distance, duration, cadence)
            ) {
                return alert('Inputs have to be a positive number.');
            }
            workout = new Running([lat, lng], distance, duration, cadence);
        }
        
        // -> if cycling, create cycling object
        
        if (type === 'cycling') {
            const elevation = +inputElevation.value;
            // -> check if data is valid
            if (
                !validInput(distance, duration, elevation) ||
                    !allPositive(distance, duration)
            )
                return alert('Inputs have to be a positive number.');
            workout = new Cycling([lat, lng], distance, duration, elevation);
        }
        
        // -> adds workout to workout array
        this.#workout.push(workout);
        
        // -> render the workout
        this._renderWorkoutMarker(workout);
        
        // -> Render workout on list
        this._renderWorkout(workout);
        
        // -> hide the form
        this._hideForm();
        
        // -> save workouts to storage
        this._setLocalStorage();
    }
    
    _renderWorkoutMarker(workout) {
        // -> DISPLAY MAP MARKER ON SUBMIT
        
        L.marker(workout.coords)
            .addTo(this.#map)
            .bindPopup(
                L.popup({
                    minWidth: 250,
                    maxWidth: 100,
                    autoClose: false,
                    closeOnClick: false,
                    className: `${workout.type}-popup`,
                })
            )
            .setPopupContent(
                `${workout.type === 'cycling' ? '‍♂️' : '‍♂️'} ${workout.description}`
            )
            .openPopup();
    }
    _renderWorkout(workout) {
        let html = `
            <li class="workout workout--${workout.type}" data-id="${workout.id}">
            <h2 class="workout__title">${workout.description}</h2>
            <div class="workout__details">
            <span class="workout__icon">${
                workout.type === 'cycling' ? '‍♂️' : '‍♂️'
            }</span>
            <span class="workout__value">${workout.distance}</span>
            <span class="workout__unit">km</span>
            </div>
            <div class="workout__details">
            <span class="workout__icon">⏱</span>
            <span class="workout__value">${workout.duration}</span>
            <span class="workout__unit">min</span>
            </div>
            `;
        
        if (workout.type === 'running') {
            html += `
                <div class="workout__details">
                <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
                <span class="workout__value">${workout.pace.toFixed(1)}</span>
                <span class="workout__unit">min/km</span>
                </div>
                <div class="workout__details">
                <span class="workout__icon"></span>
                <span class="workout__value">${workout.cadence.toFixed(1)}</span>
                <span class="workout__unit">spm</span>
                </div>
                </li>
                `;
        }
        if (workout.type === 'cycling') {
            html += `
                <div class="workout__details">
                <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
                <span class="workout__value">${workout.speed.toFixed(1)}</span>
                <span class="workout__unit">km/h</span>
                </div>
                <div class="workout__details">
                <span class="workout__icon">⛰</span>
                <span class="workout__value">${workout.elevation.toFixed(1)}</span>
                <span class="workout__unit">m</span>
                </div>
                </li>
                `;
        }
        form.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
    }
    _setLocalStorage() {
        localStorage.setItem('workouts', JSON.stringify(this.#workout));
    }
    _getLocalStorage() {
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workouts'));
        
        if (!data) return;
        
        this.#workout = data;
        console.log(typeof this.#workout);
        
        this.#workout.forEach(work => {
            this._renderWorkout(work);
        });
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof this.#workout);` show?

Comment: Hi Barmar, when i run the typeof for this.#workout it returns 'object'. Which is why I' confused why it's not working.

Comment: @source-ali Not all objects have a `forEach` method. Try logging the value itself, or also `Array.isArray(data)`

Comment: have you checked your "workouts" value saved in localstorage.

Comment: You can use DevTools to examine the contents of LocalStorage, so you can see what's in the `workouts` item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like  the result of  `const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workouts'));` is not Array.

So you can check it as below

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workouts')));
```

Comment: Hi Promet99, thank for your help. I'm actually not using typescript (never have) so I don't know if this would apply? Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hey, my mistake. In your case, the problem is that ```JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('workouts'));``` is not array.

Make sure it is array

Comment: Thanks guys, it turns out it wasn't an array for some reason, I made the changes to fix it. Appreciate the help!